# Store object of a custom class in a remeberSaveable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

So i have created a data class called Country. It has some basic countries related properties like name, cc, flag etc.
So I've made a long list of countries. Where each country is Country object. So when i select a country, I store that object using rememberSaveable.

```
var state by remeberSaveable{mutableStateOf<Country?>(null)}
```

So when i select a country and save it in syate it saves properly. However when i rotate my device, app crashes. It only crashes if there is a value of type Country in state.
It will also crash if I have set a value of type Country within the code.
For eg:

```
val initCountry = Country(......)
var state by remeberSaveable{mutableStateOf<Country?>(initCountry)}
```

I have searched some article aslo trued to implement a saver. But nothing changed.

Comment: try to follow https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state. there is an example for city in the docs